# SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode not returning correct window size

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, sdl, hidpi

My Question is how to get the current window size?

It needs to be able to get the window size, both fullscreen or windowed.

I am using SDL2, Glad, OpenGL #ver 130. On Window 10 with scaling.

I initialized the window to be 1280x720.

```
SDL_CreateWindow(window, title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL |
        SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
```

It is an OpenGL context enable window.

```
SDL_GL_CreateContext
gladLoadGL
```

All I want is the get the current window size. I expected it to be 1280x720.

```
        SDL_DisplayMode dm;
        if( SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode( 0, &dm ) != 0 ) {
            //save log
        }
        printf("%dx%d\n", dm.h, dm.w);
```

The terminal output.

```
960x1707
```

And yet I am getting an odd number, 1707x960. I don't think this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

[`SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode) returns the current resolution of the given display/monitor, not the size of a window.

You want [`SDL_GetWindowSize()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSize) for the window size and [`SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize) for un-HiDPI-scaled dimensions to pass into `glViewport()`.